# How can I import sound for an animation that will be used in a Unity3D game

Tags: animation, unity, audio, effects

I am currently working on a game that will be made with Blender and Unity. I want to know how to import sound to Blender so that I can get my animations just right then export the animations AND sound to be used in Unity. Does anyone know how to do this? I would GREATLY appreciate if someone could be VERY specific in their answer or direct me towards a video or an article explaining how to do it.

Comment: You could do it in Unity since you can update the .blend file animations even mid-game. To ensure WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to *Editor Type > Video Sequence Editor*
2. Then go to *Add > Sound*

In this way you can synchronize audio with your animation in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

First of All, Create all of your animations.
Then Select the Editor Type & Change it to Video Sequence Editor.
[image: Video Sequence Editor]
Change the Video Window to 3d View to look at your animation.
in the middle Sequence Editor, press <kbd>Shift+A</kbd> for context menu (Also selectable from the menu below <kbd>Add</kbd>)and select your sound. 
[image: Sound added]